# (PVRTexTool) How do I select multiple images in the GUI??

Tags: converters, pvrtc

(Redid this question since I needed more "details")
The images can be selected one by one. They can be selected and use the "Flip along an axis" tool to fit into the model's UVs. The problem is, with tons of textures cluttering up the GUI, it might take a long time to select each texture. By the way, I am getting textures for Real Racing 3. The etc.dds textures are decompressed from the .z files using a RR3 bms script. Then I use this bms script called "dds2.bms" used to convert it to pvr. Then I can open them in PVRTexTool. The problem is that all of them are flipped vertically. As mentioned above, they can be flipped by using a tool. When I have a car with a bunch of liveries/textures, it will take a long time to select each one and flip it. Is there a way to batch flip them without using the CLI tool?

Comment: I haven't noticed a "select multiple" option, but on the panel on the left, there is a "surface browser" tab that allows you to select images by name.

Comment: Nope, only lets me select one sadly.

Comment: My apologies - I just thought you meant you were trying to select them as displayed in the main viewing window. The "surface browser" was just meant as a way of selecting them (still one at a time) but at a possibly faster rate.